# Запятая и тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

Верно ли я поставила знак (в скобках)? Или нужно просто тире, без запятой? Или двоеточие?

> Небо было холодное, грозное, тёмное (,—) цвета мокрого асфальта, ртути.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отсутствии пояснительных союзов "то есть", "именно", "а именно" и при наличии пояснения ставится тире.
Здесь есть даже обобщающе-пояснительный смысл.

В любом случае запятая не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Небо было холодное, грозное, тёмное, — цвета мокрого асфальта, ртути.

Присоединительная конструкция, **желательно использовать единый знак "запятая-тире"**, так как сообщение делится на два смысловых блока, и в каждом есть свои знаки препинания.

Если оставить только тире, то вторая часть будет относится к слову "темное", а не ко всему ряду, предложение будет иметь неясный смысл..

Answer (score 1):

А зачем запятая после "тёмное?". От чего она отделяет прилагательное? Вы же не отделяете "холодное" от "небо было", поскольку запятые ставятся между однородными членами, а не вокруг них.

Здесь достаточно тире, но литература знает примеры использования двоеточия: для подчёркивания паузой значимости сравнения.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ!